# Haskell: Why is ((.).(.)) f g equal to f . g x?

Tags: haskell, types, function-composition, combinators, pointfree

Could you please explain the meaning of the expression ((.).(.))?
As far as I know (.) has the type (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c.

Comment: `((.).(.)) f g` is not equal to `f . g x` (but `((.).(.)) f g x` is).

Answer (score 23):

`(.) . (.)` is the composition of the composition operator with itself.

If we look at

```
((.) . (.)) f g x
```

we can evaluate that a few steps, first we parenthesise,

```
((((.) . (.)) f) g) x
```

then we apply, using `(foo . bar) arg = foo (bar arg)`:

```
~> (((.) ((.) f)) g) x
~> (((.) f) . g) x
~> ((.) f) (g x)
~> f . g x
```

More principled,

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

So, using `(.)` as the first argument of `(.)`, we must unify

```
b -> c
```

with

```
(v -> w) -> (u -> v) -> (u -> w)
```

That yields

```
b = v -> w
c = (u -> v) -> (u -> w)
```

and

```
(.) (.) = ((.) .) :: (a -> v -> w) -> a -> (u -> v) -> (u -> w)
```

Now, to apply that to `(.)`, we must unify the type

```
a -> v -> w
```

with the type of `(.)`, after renaming

```
(s -> t) -> (r -> s) -> (r -> t)
```

which yields

```
a = s -> t
v = r -> s
w = r -> t
```

and thus

```
(.) . (.) :: (s -> t) -> (u -> r -> s) -> (u -> r -> t)
```

and from the type we can (almost) read that `(.) . (.)` applies a function (of one argument) to the result of a function of two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an answer already, here's a slightly different take on it.

In [combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) `(.)` is [***B**-combinator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system) : `Babc = a(bc)`. When writing combinator expressions it is customary to assume that every identifier consists of one letter only, and omit white-space in application, to make the expressions more readable. Of course the usual currying applies: `abcde` is `(((ab)c)d)e` and vice versa.

`(.)` is **B**, so `((.) . (.))` == `(.) (.) (.)` == **BBB**. So,

```
BBBfgxy = B(Bf)gxy = (Bf)(gx)y = Bf(gx)y = (f . g x) y    
 abc        a  bc                 a b  c
```

We can throw away both `y`s at the end (this is known as [eta-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion): `Gy=Hy` --> `G=H`, if `y` does not appear  inside `H`<sup>1</sup>). But also, another way to present this, is

```
BBBfgxy = B(Bf)gxy = ((f .) . g) x y = f (g x y)     -- (.) f == (f .)
-- compare with:       (f .) g x = f (g x)
```

`((f .) . g) x y` might be easier to type in than `((.).(.)) f g x y`, but YMMV.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, with [**S** combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), defined as `Sfgx = fx(gx)`, without regard for that rule we could write

```
Sfgx = fx(gx) = B(fx)gx = (f x . g) x
Sfg = B(fx)g = (f x . g)   --- WRONG, what is "x"?
```

which is nonsense.